# Migration code to prevent date overlapping in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rake

I have a Ruby on Rails project, in which I need to ensure that dates (start_date, end_date) for an **Period** class do not overlap (partially or fully contained) between periods.

An event class has many **PeriodDays** associated, which already ensure no repeating days can be added to the same Period. I've seen that this can be done in pure PostgreSQL, but is there a way to write an ActiveRecord Migration so that two periods do not overlap?

**Additional Info**: In this case, a Period's start and end dates are always inside the same month.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on how to write a migration that adds a constraint that would prevent bad data from being inserted?